# Is there a proper psychological term to describe "integrity" i.e. acting according to ones convictions/values?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Im trying to find out (for a paper) if there is a link between not being able to act according to ones own values, due to abuse or other factors, and depression.

My issue is that the only term I can think of is "integrity" and I havent found any literature investigating "integrity" and mental health outcomes.

So Im wondering if Im missing the correct term.

Comment: Interesting.  Check [akrasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akrasia) for potential leads.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question because psychology and its application will involve looking at what you are referring to in all sorts of ways.

To me, what you are referring to is **congruence**. One of the prominent people who discussed congruence was Carl Rogers, who developed the Person Centred approach to psychotherapy as opposed to the psychodynamic/psychoanalytic approach.

In its simple terms, [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Rogers#Incongruity) was referred to by Carl Rogers to involve the *real self* and the *ideal self*. In this simplified example, if your real (current/actually possible) self matches your "ideal" (sometimes impossible) self you have built in your mind, you are living congruently.

As I said, this is a very simplistic description for the initial introduction to the concept, and when you fully immerse yourself in the concept, it is multifaceted and lies at the heart of Carl Rogers' [19 Propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Rogers#Nineteen_propositions).

You have self-image congruence, mood congruence, values congruence, political congruence, cultural congruence... The list goes on.